# How to upload files from a plugin to wordpress media library?

Tags: html, wordpress, drag-and-drop

I need to developed a front-end drag and drop plug in. First I collect the html5 drag and droping code.

Download the source code in zip format - https://github.com/Mashpy/html5-drag-and-drop-upload/archive/master.zip

Put the files in localhost and open. If you upload files it will be uploades in "uploads" folder. Because I put code in " /js/mashpy.js " that this time "upload.php" file will be loaded and it will send the files in "uploads" folder.

That means this process work something like this -
index.html -- js/mashpy.js -- upload.php -- send file to "uploads"  -- dump.php will show the result that upload successfully.

Now I have to developed a front-end drag and drop plug in. But I don't know how to upload files in wordpress media library. In this source code upload.php works which send files to "uploads" folder. But what happened in wordpress? How to send files to wordpress media library?

Comment: Please, note that we won't download and analyze your full plugin code. You have to put here only the relevant parts, that's something called [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply upload files to `wp-content/uploads/`. They won't show up in Media Library. You need to use WordPress function [`media_handle_upload($file,$post_id)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload), passing `0` as post ID (so, it's not attached to any post/page).

Something like:

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
        }
        $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, 0 );
    }   
}
```

You can study this plugin to see how it does it: [Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/). And also research in WordPress Answers [for examples](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=media_handle_upload%20is:answer) of this function usage.